# Video read on Safari, Downloaded on Chrome and not working on Firefox

Tags: flash, firefox, video, encoding, safari

I have a problem concerning a video posted on a website :

- When using Safari, it's perfectly working (the video is read)
- When using Chrome, the video is downloaded
- When using Firefox, the video is totally not working, the page displays a big mess

The URL is http://www.cekal.eu/pages_php/files_upload/documents/CklArcAil_FlmIll415_00_t15k05_00.mp4

Would you know what's going on ? I have no access to the source code...

Thank you

Comment: I've a post which is speaking about something like this, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27995270/2256820), I think that can help you to understand what happen ... For info, the format of your video is MPEG-4 Visual with AAC as audio ... for me it was just played in Safari with VLC plugin ...

Comment: Ok thank you I'm having a look at this.